# Access Photo Library without using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Everyone.
Is there any way of accessing photos on my iphone without using UIImagePickerController?
Can I somehow use NSFileManager for this purpose? If not then is there any alternative?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Assets Library Framework allows you to access the photos and videos managed by the Photos application, which includes those that are in the saved photos album, those coming from iTunes and those that were directly imported into the device

See [the official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) for more information.

There's also a very good tutorial [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/) on how to use it, including a video.